# Joomla: onContentAfterSave not triggered

Tags: php, joomla

I'm developing a Joomla plugin. Unfortunately, the necessary event is not fired. This means that the following code never gets executed:

```
public function onContentAfterSave($context, &$article, $isNew)
{
 ....
}
```

I have developed the plugin as usual. All other used events work fine.
Can this be an internal Joomla \ PHP bug or am I missing something?

Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8k PHP/5.3.3

Joomla! 2.5.4 Stable [ Ember ] 2-April-2012 14:00 GMT

Comment: When you say "all other events work fine" do you mean that you have over events like "onContentBeforeDisplay" for example, in the same plugin file and they are working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you *definitely* installed and enabled the plugin? It's easy to forget the latter, in particular.

Comment: Sure. It works, I see that other functions \ events from it are being executed.

Comment: And are you certain the callback function isn't executing? If you add  `die('test')` as the very first line of that function, for example, does it get fired?

Comment: Bobby Jack, you've solved it ;) You can post this as an answer and I will mark it as correct one. Thanks!

Comment: @semyon: have you determined *why* the callback wasn't executing? If it's for a reasonably common reason, it's worth adding as an answer and marking it correct. If it's something very localised, it may just be better to close the question.

Comment: the callback was executing. My fault was in using another ways of determining this (echo), but I forgot that Joomla! can modify output buffer so no messages will appear. `Die()` is more easier-to-determine way ;)

Answer (score 4):

There's probably something not matching between the plugin name in your .xml file and the plugin name in your .php file.

### [PluginName].php

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.event.plugin');  // I've also seen joomla.plugin.plugin.
                                 // Perhaps and older version
class plg[PluginGroup][PluginName]
{
    public function onContentAfterSave( $context, &$article, $isNew  )
    {
      // $db = JFactory::GetDBO();
      // etc...
    }
}
?>
```

### [PluginName].xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extension type="plugin" version="2.5.0" group="[PluginGroup]">
<name>[PluginName]</name>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<author></author>
<creationDate></creationDate>
<copyright></copyright>
<license></license>
<authorEmail></authorEmail>
<authorUrl></authorUrl>
<description></description>
<files>
  <filename plugin="[PluginName]">[PluginName].php</filename>
  <filename>[PluginName].xml</filename>
  <filename>index.html</filename>       
</files>
</extension>
```

Otherwise, please post more information:

1. What else in your [pluginname].php and [pluginname].xml files.
2. Have you installed the plugin correctly?
3. Have you published the plugin after installation?

Comment: +1 for my problem it was the name of the class. I changed to the correct format as suggested and the method gets fired. thank you